# Typescript interface to ensure array containers objects with all values covered

Tags: typescript

I'm wondering if its possible to ensure and array has objects with a key value that covers the keys of another interface. hard to explain, but i can demonstrate what i want to happeen.

```
interface Test {
   prop1:string; 
   prop2:string;
   prop3:string;
}
```

```
const array = [
   { property:'prop1', ...rest },
   { property: 'prop2', ...rest },
   { property: 'prop3', ...rest }
]

const array2 = [
   { property:'prop1', ...rest },
   { property: 'prop2', ...rest },
]
```

array 2 should not be valid as it doesnt contain an object with { property: 'prop3' }

atm I have

```
interface Value {
test: string;
test1: string;
}
interface MyListType<T> {
  property: keyof T & string;
}
const a:MyListType<Value>[] = [{
   property: 'sdfs' // error not of type 'test' | 'test1'
}]
```

Comment: There is no simple "exhaustive array" type in TypeScript.  You can write a union-of-all-possible-arrays which will blow out the compiler resources for arrays of length 8 or more.  You can write a generic constraint and use a helper function like `myListType(...)` which will complain if you don't pass it an array with all the values.  How big is the key set of the target interface? How do you plan to use values of your list type (code example)?  The use case is the most important.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why not just use type `Array<Test>`? Because the possible error will be "too deep"? (As in `const t: Array<Test> = [ {prop1: 'a', prop2: 'b', prop3: 'c'} ];` )
https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCoQM5mQbwLABQyxADlAPYkCMAXFlKAOYDcyhxyZlATHWAyBbtSFEgGY+AoQQC+hQgnIgsyMLWQBBKFDgBPADzosAPmQBeZAG1cXajWQByOA4A0nUb0cAjV+8oTHBAcZZABdZnkCAHoo5ABRbXIoBSUVME8tHQMjMFMLaxxbdSdfW08HHxDwwiA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no easy way to describe exhaustive tuples in TypeScript. One way is to create a union type of all possible combinations.

```
type MyListType<T> = [keyof T] extends [never] 
  ? [] : 
  {
    [K in keyof T]: [{ property: K }, ...MyListType<Record<Exclude<keyof T, K>, any>>]
  }[keyof T]
```

This will correctly detect if an array has all the necessary elements.

```
const array: MyListType<Test> = [
   { property:'prop1' },
   { property: 'prop2' },
   { property: 'prop3' }
]

//    Error
const array2: MyListType<Test> = [
   { property:'prop1' },
   { property: 'prop2' },
]
```

But be aware that it will extremely computationally expensive with bigger objects.

---

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCoQM5mQbwLABQyxADlAPYkCMAXFlKAOYDcyhxyZlATHWAyBbtSFEgGY+AoQQC+hQmACeJFAFlFAGWBZUyiAB5UAPmQBeZAG0A1hEXkYaALrIIAD0ggAJhksgIAN2hnYQB+S2caNiJcYWILAGlkUGQbOwdUR0iLHE5RaCVIxJkAGmQAOgr1LR09fQAlCARyKE99AFFXBAAbAFdPA1T7NFL4o1K4EEUjI0dhGWtbIYz5AhWmkCxkOCgoOEVIqu0wXRVDTDATcwtYnK4VKAKAcjuqR+QSm9zKfP3kZ9FuG8PtFcF97gU-ncxEDCLNVgQAPQIjjINo7ZqEdabba7RS8ZCHGqndBYS6WT53H40f6UV7vYoUvIPX40kiA+mwoA)

Comment: Thank you, yeah i was worried about that, i'm working in a fairly large project and wanted to implement this for a few things, but think with it being so complicated and computationally expensive, i'll give it a miss. Thanks for the answer though.